# Is there a way to send a Python command from a Raspberry Pi via USB to a PC?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, pynput

So I know it may be a little strange, but I'm wondering if there is a way to send a python command over serial communication to make my PC do something. Let's say I'm using the pynput library for example, and I want to make my PC type "Success!" into a text document if the Pi turns an LED on.

Frankly, I've looked seemingly everywhere, and I don't even know where to begin. I think my Google-fu is lacking, since I've looked into pyserial and dug through several Raspberry Pi related topics, and scoured YouTube, but haven't found a single thing. I've found videos on USB communication between Pi and Arduino, but nothing between Pi and PCs for example.

**EDIT:** I've received some advice to clarify my setup. Currently, I'm working with a Pi Zero W running a local python script that emulates a keyboard. I have a Micro USB to USB A cable connecting my Pi to Windows PC, and I'm running the default Pi OS. The keyboard emulator on the Pi will make the Pi type whatever I want, I was wondering if I could send that "typing command" to my Windows PC. Basically, I tell python to type something, but I want python to tell my PC to type it instead of my Pi.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify exactly how Raspi and PC are connected and what OS the PC is running. And what programs/scripts are running on both.

Comment: Let's assume the PC is running windows. For now, I'd like to connect the Pi to the PC using a USB cable. The PC wouldn't be running any script, but the Raspi would send the command to type something to the PC over USB when and LED turns on.

Comment: Sending a remote command to a specially setup PC is very different than generically sending text over a USB cable - in the latter case it seems like you'd have to emulate a USB keyboard. Perhaps you should clarify your setup a little more.

Comment: Maybe consider an Arduino acting as `hid` device https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/

Comment: Ohhhhh my goodness, I think y'all have shown me the light. Instead of trying to offset the operation I should be turning the Pi into an HID Gadget Keyboard. I found a neat article thanks to this change in keywording. If I turn it into an HID Gadget, would I still be able to use the Pi normally? Like will it still power a touchscreen or would I be able to use the GPIO pins?